# An error while trying to install Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I recently tried to install Android Studio but I encountered an error while doing it. It stops with the following error message:

```
Extract: android-sdk. 7z and installation aborted.
```

I have already tried to reinstall it but it failed ...again.

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: Do you have enough free disk space?

Answer (score 5):

I also ran into this issue. I had to unistall some apps and free up some storage space. Once I did this I tried to reinstall the android studio. It worked. You will need to have at least 4-5GB available in order for this to work. You could try to also move some of your bigger files that may not be used as frequently to an external drive. Hope that this works, but if so then please let us know so that it can be used to help others. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the issue.I was trying to install studio on separate drive say D. D drive had more than 8 GB space free.But my C drive was almost full.So i had to delete unused files on C ,make some space and then i could successfully install studio on D drive.

Hope this helps !